# yii2 form doesn't submit

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

when I press submit button noting happens, even the page doesn't refresh. I have checked the code too many times. I don't know what is wrong with it. 
I am using Yii2 framework the basic-app and Apache server.

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\web\controller;
use app\models\Form;

class FormController extends Controller{

    public function actionForm(){

        $model = new Form;
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have entered data successfuly!');
        }
        return $this->render('view',['model'=>$model]);
    }
}
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\model;

class Form extends Model{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules(){
        return [
        [['name','email'],'required'],
        ['email','email']
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

View:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php
    if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')){
        echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
    }
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'email'); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

at the end.